# Minimize $\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2(1-x)(x+3)}$ on $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, rational-functions

One can differentiate to obtain

$$f'(x)=\frac{2(x^2+3)(x^2+x-1)}{x^3(1-x)^2(x+3)^2}.$$

Thus, the unique stationary point is $x=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, which is also the minimum point on $(0,1)$. But can we solve by a more **elementary** method, for example, by **inequalities**?

Comment: Basic algebra could show that the minimum is minimal, but for this function I don't see it helping to find the minimum if we don't already know it.

Comment: A minimum must be attained since $g(x) = 1/f(x)$ is non-negative and extends to be continuous on $[0,1]$ with $g(0)=g(1)=0$, so $g$ attains its maximum in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Maybe it helps that the minimum occurs when $x^2=1-x$